# Matching coordinate with predefined address

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, ssrs-2012

I Have 2 tables, 1. " Address_Table" and 2.Coordinate_Table

I want to match the coordinate record from table 2  with the nearest address from table 1 with the range of 50 meters. if not found then return the coordinate.

Address_Table :

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ADD_ID |  Longitude  |  Latitude   | Range | Address |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
|      1 | 72.03092000 | 33.28729000 |    50 | abcd    |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

Coordinate_Table:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+
| Cor_id |   Co_Lat    |   Co_GLng   |
+--------+-------------+-------------+
|   8450 | 72.03092011 | 33.28729005 |
|   8451 | 73.03099001 | 32.28729901 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Results_View :

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
| Cor_id |   Co_Lat    |   Co_GLng   |        Address          |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
|   8450 | 72.03092011 | 33.28729005 | abcd                    |
|   8451 | 73.03099001 | 32.28729901 | 73.03099001,32.28729901 |
+--------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Specify `Primarykey` column and `Foreignkey` columns in both the tables.

Comment: Primarykey for each table is the ID .

Comment: How to calculate distance?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT
    CT.Id,
    CT.Co_Lat,
    CT.Co_GLng,
    [Address] = COALESCE(AD.[Address],cast(CT.Co_Lat as varchar(50))+','+cast(CT.Co_GLng as varchar(50)),'')
    FROM Coordinate_Table CT
       LEFT JOIN Address_Table AD
          ON CT.Co_Lat BETWEEN AD.Longitude+0.00000005 AND AD.Longitude-0.00000005
             AND CT.Co_GLng BETWEEN AD.Latitude+0.00000005 AND AD.Latitude-0.00000005
```

Comment: i got this error : Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Just updated the answer to add a Cast operation. try now

Comment: Thank You much , but it didn't work for me.it only concatenate the coordinate, but address not showing.